# Map domain result into http result

Tags: rust, actix-web

I'm trying to build an HTTP Server using Actix web framework in Rust.
I'm used to segregate Business Model and Business Error from HttpResponse.
For doing that, I've my service, CredentialService, that exposes a method that returns a result `Result<String, CredentialServiceError>`.

My WebServer exposes an API `POST /login` that accepts `username` and `password` and returns a JWT.

The enum `CredentialServiceError' is the following

```rust
use derive_more::{Display, Error};

#[derive(Debug, Display, Error)]
pub enum CredentialServiceError {
    NoCredentialFound,
    ErrorOnGeneratingJWT,
}
```

My handler is something like:

```rust
async fn login(request_body: web::Json<LoginRequest>, credential_service: web::Data<CredentialService>) -> Result<HttpResponse> {
    let request_body: LoginRequest = request_body.0;

    let jwt = credential_service.login(request_body.username, request_body.password);

    let response: Result<LoginResponse, CredentialServiceError> = jwt.map(|jwt| {
        LoginResponse { jwt }
    });
    response.into()
}
```

I receive this error:

```
the trait bound `std::result::Result<actix_web::HttpResponse, actix_web::Error>: std::convert::From<std::result::Result<model::LoginResponse, credential_service::CredentialServiceError>>` is not satisfied

the trait `std::convert::From<std::result::Result<model::LoginResponse, credential_service::CredentialServiceError>>` is not implemented for `std::result::Result<actix_web::HttpResponse, actix_web::Error>`

help: the following implementations were found:
        <std::result::Result<(), idna::uts46::Errors> as std::convert::From<idna::uts46::Errors>>
        <std::result::Result<(), ring::error::Unspecified> as std::convert::From<ring::bssl::Result>>
        <std::result::Result<miniz_oxide::MZStatus, miniz_oxide::MZError> as std::convert::From<&miniz_oxide::StreamResult>>
        <std::result::Result<miniz_oxide::MZStatus, miniz_oxide::MZError> as std::convert::From<&miniz_oxide::StreamResult>>
      and 2 others
note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `std::convert::Into<std::result::Result<actix_web::HttpResponse, actix_web::Error>>` for `std::result::Result<model::LoginResponse, credential_service::CredentialServiceError>`rustc(E0277)
```

I've also tried to implement

```rust
impl error::ResponseError for CredentialServiceError { ... }
impl Into<HttpResponse> for LoginResponse { ... }
```

The the error doesn't change.

So, how can I convert `Result<String, CredentialServiceError>` into `Result<HttpResponse>` ?

Answer (score 1):

So the problem you are facing is, that you want to convert your result into the Result that actix_web functions expect. I hope I understood that correctly.

I don't see an other way than to map your Result to the expected one. There are different ways you could accomplish that. If you would want to keep the implementation details in your `LoginResponse` struct you could use the [Into](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.Into.html) trait.

```rust
impl Into<HttpResponse> for LoginResponse {
    fn into(self) -> HttpResponse {
        HttpResponse::Ok().body(self.jwt)
    }
}
```

If you don't really care you can use the [map](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html#method.map_err) functions provided by `Result`.

```rust
fn map_credential_error(error: CredentialServiceError) -> actix_web::error::Error {
    match error {
        CredentialServiceError::NoCredentialFound => {
            actix_web::error::ErrorUnauthorized("Not authorized")
        }
        CredentialServiceError::ErrorOnGeneratingJWT => {
            actix_web::error::ErrorInternalServerError("Something went wrong generating your jwt")
        }
    }
}
```

So in the end your login function would look something like this.

```rust
async fn login(
    request_body: web::Json<LoginRequest>,
    credential_service: web::Data<CredentialService>,
) -> Result<HttpResponse> {
    let request_body: LoginRequest = request_body.0;

    let jwt = credential_service.login(request_body.username, request_body.password);

    let response: Result<HttpResponse, CredentialServiceError> =
        jwt.map(|jwt| LoginResponse { jwt }.into());

    response.map_err(map_credential_error)
}
```

Hope I could help and that I understood your question.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @Julius-Kreutz's answer you may consider `impl ResponseError` trait [Source from Chanda, Abhishek](https://auth0.com/blog/build-an-api-in-rust-with-jwt-authentication-using-actix-web/). For example if your `CredentialServiceError` is an enum like:

```
#[derive(Debug, Display)]
pub enum CredentialServiceError {
    #[display(fmt = "Internal Server Error")]
    InternalServerError,

    #[display(fmt = "BadRequest: {}", _0)]
    BadRequest(String),

    #[display(fmt = "JWKSFetchError")]
    JWKSFetchError,
}
```

Then yuo can do something like:

```
impl ResponseError for CredentialServiceError {
    fn error_response(&self) -> HttpResponse {
        match self {
            CredentialServiceError::InternalServerError => {
                HttpResponse::InternalServerError().json("Internal Server Error, Please try later")
            }
            CredentialServiceError::BadRequest(ref message) => HttpResponse::BadRequest().json(message),
            ServiceError::JWKSFetchError => {
                HttpResponse::InternalServerError().json("Could not fetch JWKS")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

To enable the `.into()`

Comment: `impl error::ResponseError for CredentialServiceError { ... }` is not the same?

Comment: @allevo It is the same, however I wasn't certain *how* he impl'd the error so i gave him an example a boilerplate that when combined with Julius-Kreutz's answer (above) would provide him the result :P